# CSS opacity setting

Tags: css, firebug, opacity

I have the following CSS class:

```
.transparency
{    
  -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

When I look at the class in the loaded CSS file on firebug, the class shows up empty. So in firebug, it basically looks like this:

```
.transparencyPlayPause
{
}
```

When I change the class contents to this, the class is no longer empty

.transparencyPlayPause
    {
     display:none;
    }

Has anyone else seen such behavior?

Comment: Check out [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity#Browser_Compatibility) for browser compatability (Firefox uses plain `opacity`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those properties are supported by Firefox, so Firebug doesn't see any parsed properties inside the rule.

You should get rid of `-webkit-` and `-moz-`, and add `-ms-filter`.